# How to create descriptive table with Stargazer for categorical variables?

Tags: r, stargazer

This code:

```
library(stargazer)

data("ToothGrowth")
df<-ToothGrowth
df$len[2]<-NA
df$supp[5]<-NA
df$supp<-factor(df$supp)
stargazer(df, type = "html")
```

gives me the descriptive table for continues variables only and ignores categorical variables. How to make it produce descriptive table for categorical variables (at least absolute number in each categories and percentage)?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, that it `stargazer` supports numerical categories:

```
stargazer(mtcars, type="text")
```

You may relabel your factor strings into numbers. Or dummify your factor with various packages. Same answer was given here, 5 years ago:

[Output each factor level as dummy variable in stargazer summary statistics table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912957/output-each-factor-level-as-dummy-variable-in-stargazer-summary-statistics-table)